# Good Hash function? (32-bit too small, 64-bit too large)

Tags: java, hash, md5, apache-commons, uniqueidentifier

I need to generate a hash value used for uniqueness of many billions of records in Java.  Trouble is, I only have 16 numeric digits to play with.  In researching this, I have found algorithms for 32-bit hash, which return Java integers.  But this is too small, as it only has a range of +/ 2 billion, and have will have more records that that.  I cannot go to a 64-bit hash, as that will give me numeric values back that are too large (+/ 4 quintillion, or 19 digits).  Trouble is, I am dealing with a legacy system that is forcing me into a static key length of 16 digits.

Suggestions?  I know no hash function will guarantee uniqueness, but I need a good one that will fit into these restrictions.

Thanks

Comment: How do you plan to store the data? Will all records be stored in memory (if you have enough memory to do that) or will you implement paging to disk or something similar? If you do use pages/buckets, you can use different 32-bit hash functions for each bucket.

Comment: @Doug - I honestly don't know of a proven method that would allow you to do this with only 16-bits considering even a 32-bit not enough combinations.

Comment: Could you clarify if that is 16 digits as in something less than 9999999999999999, or 16 digits as in 16 alphanumeric chars? Can you save the number as something other than digits (like hexadecimal or base 36)?

Comment: Goldy locks said "48-bits was just right". I have not looked much for one but a quick google search gave some hits of others looking so one might exist.

Comment: PaoloVictor, The data is for a legacy key on a mainframe, with a current format of 16 numeric (not alpha, not even hex) digits.  Theo, something less than 999999999999999, numerically.

Comment: And, instead of a hash, how about a primary key with auto-increase?

Comment: The right word you search for your digits is not **numeric**, it is **decimal**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your generated hash is too large you can just mod it with your keyspace max to make it fit.

```
myhash = hash64bitvalue % 10^16
```

Comment: The chance you will get hash-collision raises enormous, as you said it has to be unique.

Comment: @Martjin: "The chance you will get hash-collision raises enormous" - I think not, that's not how hashes work; A true hash in a keyspace mod a smaller keyspace is just as good a hash in the smaller key space.

Comment: @Andrew: I don't think so: extreme example: hash1 = 40000; hash2 = 20000, but we are limited to 2 bytes: hash1_2byte = hash1 % 4; hash2_2byte = hash2 % 4; Now they are the same.

Comment: @Andrew Could you provide some reference for that? When you add a mod to the hash function, won't the result actually be a new hash function? How can we prove this function is always "as good" as the original?

Comment: @Paolo: A simple proof; consider a hash function h that distributes evenly and randomly over N; now consider a smaller range M such that M < N. For any sampling of N the h will produce a uniform distribution; I choose a sampling of every M items which means this sampling must be uniform as well. Martinj arguemt is invalid since I said "as good a hash in the smaller key space". He simply showed that more collisions exist in a 2 byte domain (yeah it's smaller) but *all* hash function in this domain will produce more collisions.

Comment: @Andrew I understand that the sampling of M < N keys would be uniform on the [0..N] range, but would K(N) % M be on the [0..M] range, which is the case for this problem? Rephrasing: would [key(N) % M < M AND have a uniform distribution] for all N?

Comment: @Paolo: Yes, unless the hash function in N had some flaw/limitation. The idea of most good hashing functions is that it is hard to construct *any* sampling that would result in more collisions. If you have some spare time, take something like sha1 or md5 and mod it some smaller value (say 2^32) and run some tests on it. The mod trick is pretty common method to use for this type of domain reduction.

Comment: Okay. Is this python test correct? http://pastebin.com/qymjQEV9 It prints "88266 collided with hash 3775075157" (The int-to-string conversion bugs me, but I don't have enough time to look at that right now). Edit2: I've just noticed that you've written "more collisions", so you say that collisions are still possible? Because that was what I was thinking all along

Comment: @Paolo: Nice job! I think it is correct. But I don't write python.

Comment: @Paolo: you have only found a collision (most hash will have these), you did not show that the moded values was any worse than any other hash function in M. When I said "run some tests" I meant test for uniformity and randomness.

Comment: Yeah, that was what I meant by my edit. I understood that you asserted that the distribution was uniform _and collisions were not possible_. I believed that the OP wanted a solution with no collisions (which is kinda impossible if the number of keys is greater than N). That's why I asked if the data fitted in memory.

Answer (score 2):

If you are limited to 16 decimal digits, your key space contains 10^16 values. 
Even if you find a hash that gives uniform distribution on your data set, due to [Birthday Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_paradox) you will have a 50% chance of collision on ~10^8 items of data, which is an order of magnitude less than your billions of records.

This means that you cannot use any kind of hash alone and rely on uniqueness.

A straightforward solution is to use a global counter instead. If global counter is infeasible, counters with preallocated ranges can be used. For example, 6 most significant digits denote fixed data source index, 10 least significant digits contain monotonous counter maintained by that data source.

Comment: Have considered a global counter, but trying to avoid it.  This will be a distributed app, and outside of using a MySql sequence (which I am currently doing), or something similar, I am not sure I would keep track of sequences.

Comment: @Doug Houck - Unfortunately there is no way around math... Unless you have something in the data itself that is unique to the data source, you won't be able to guarantee uniqueness without something like a global counter.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to store your hashes in a human readable form (hex, as you said). Just store the 64-bit long datatype (generated by a 64-bit hash function) in your database, which is only 8 bytes. And not the 19 bytes of which you were scared off.

If that isn't a solution, improve the legacy system.

---

Edit: Wait!

64-bit: 2<sup>64</sup> =

```
18446744073709551616
```

16 hex-digits: 16<sup>16</sup> =

```
18446744073709551616
```

Exact fit! So make a hex representation of your 64-bit hash, and there you are.

Answer (score 1):

So your restriction is 53 bit?

For my understanding order number of bit in hashcode doesn't affect its value (order and value of bit are fully independent from each other). So you could get 64-bit hash function and use only last 53 bits from it. And you must use binary operations for this ( hash64 & (1<<54 - 1) ) not arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

If you can save 16 alphanumeric characters then you can use a hexadecimal representation and pack 16^16 bits into 16 chars. 16^16 is 2^64.